# Jekyll output variable raw

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to output the contents of a variable in raw format. Right now I have something like this:

`{{ content }}`

but I want to not do any processing of the page content. So if my page content is:

`this text should be {{ literal }}`

I would like it to generate html corresponding to exactly that, i.e. not do any variable expansion on "{{ literal }}". Is there a way to do this? I had expected a filter to be able to do this but I can't find it.

Thank you.

Comment: I've removed my answer, it does what you asked in your post, but not what you wanted, and I dont want to leave an incorrect answer sitting around. You seem to want to be able to resolve one, and only one, layer of text expansion. I'm pretty sure thats not possible. You can either print the variable(and all its contents), or raw print it for no contents.

Answer (score 0):

Make your page content this:

```
this text should be {% raw %}{{ literal }}{% endraw %}
```

Or you could do:

```
{% raw %}
this text should be {{ literal }}
{% endraw %}
```

And then on the page you'll see:

```
this text should be {{ literal }}
```

The raw tags are mentioned in the documentation [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/).

Comment: This doesn't exactly solve my problem because I don't want to change the page contents since they are in another language (for me, bibtex). At the same time, this does not seem possible to do in the current version of Jekyll.

Comment: I edited my answer. Does that help? You can put the raw tags around the whole thing. Or you could just syntax highlighting instead.

Comment: Syntax highlighting might work, I'll have to try it.